# Django admin translation disable or custom language

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin

I want to disable i18n in django admin.
Or rewrite `django.utils.translation` methods (`gettext`, `gettext_lazy` and other).
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546569/django-i18n-how-to-not-translate-the-admin-site)
works fine, but some apps working incorect (because depends of language selecting). Web site have Russian as default language, but admin panel I want to create in English or Other language. So i have only `settings.LANGUAGES = (('ru', 'Russian'))`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write your own middleware to activate desired language in those urls:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/

It should look something like this: [set language within a django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336785/set-language-within-a-django-view)

```
def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path == '/thirdpartyapp/':
            activate('ru')
```