# How to manage system languages from django admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there some way to enable/disable or add/delete system languages from django admin interface? Since [Django says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/):

> "It reads metadata in your model to provide a powerful and production-ready interface that content producers can immediately use to start adding content to the site."

And [django book tells us](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/):

> "This is a Web-based interface, limited to trusted site administrators, that enables the adding, editing and deletion of site content."

I assume that main point is the power of manage content site. Then if my language setting enables content in some language in my site, why does django not allows me to modify it? (add/delete language to site).

I would have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I think your question is unclear, I didn't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Lara I have added an image to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to translate the Admin interface itself? If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546569/django-i18n-how-to-not-translate-the-admin-site) might help. Do you expect to have translation files in DB, in the admin/i18n? I don't think this is not how Django works, it works with `.po`/`.mo` files.

The [internationalization documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/) is really good, maybe a bit too big to digest when you just start, but Django has several switches to control what you want.

A good place to understand what switch to use for your need (at least I found it very interesting) is the [implementation notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#implementation-notes) paragraph in there, and [how Django discovers translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) which gives a HLD of the logic.

Sorry if my answer look off-topic, but as Lara, I feel like I don't completely understand your question.